# Unknown error while trying to lock file error while editing document from SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-365, office

When I am trying to edit the document which is opened from SharePoint document library I am getting "Unknown error while trying to lock file" error. I am able to view the document by clicking on the document name. But when I click on the "Edit " option available in the top yellow bar of the document I am getting the mentioned error. Our SharePoint site is configured with SSL offloading.I am able to edit the document when its browsed through HTTP and the issue only appears when the site is browsed through HTTPS URL. Many users are facing this issue. I am using Windows 7 , IE 11 and Office 2013 combination. Request your help.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved it by enabling SSL v3 and TLS 1.0 at NLB level :-)

Comment: can you elaborate on how to do that? (we are facing the same issue)